# (Scheme) How do I add 2 lists together that are different sizes

Tags: scheme

I'm completely new to scheme and I'm having trouble trying to add 2 lists of different sizes. I was wondering how do I add 2 lists of different sizes together correctly. In my code I compared the values and append '(0) to the shorter list so that they can get equal sizes, but even after doing that I can not use map to add the 2 lists. I get an error code after running the program. The results I should  be getting is '(2 4 5 4). Could anyone help me out? Thanks.

```
#lang racket

(define (add lst1 lst2)

(cond [(< (length lst1) (length lst2)) (cons (append lst1 '(0)))]  
    [else lst1])

(cond 
    ((and (null? lst1)(null? lst2)) null) 
(else
    (map  + lst1 lst2))))

;;Result should be '(2 4 6 4)
(add '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4))
```

ERROR:

```
cons: arity mismatch;
the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
expected: 2
given: 1
arguments...:
'(1 2 3 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that there are two `cond` expressions *one after the other* - both will execute, but only the result of the second one will be returned - in other words, the code is not doing what you think it's doing. Now, to solve this problem it'll be easier if we split the solution in two parts (in general, that's a good strategy!). Try this:

```
(define (fill-zeroes lst n)
  (append lst (make-list (abs n) 0)))

(define (add lst1 lst2)
  (let ((diff (- (length lst1) (length lst2))))
    (cond [(< diff 0)
           (map + (fill-zeroes lst1 diff) lst2)]
          [(> diff 0)
           (map + lst1 (fill-zeroes lst2 diff))]
          [else (map + lst1 lst2)])))
```

Explanation:

- The `fill-zeroes` procedure takes care of filling the tail of a list with a given number of zeroes
- The `add` procedure is in charge of determining which list needs to be filled, and when both lists have the right size performs the actual addition

It works as expected for any combination of list lengths:

```
(add '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2 3))
=> '(2 4 6 4)
(add '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(2 4 6 4)
(add '(1 2 3 0) '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(2 4 6 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Oscar's, slighty shorter:

```scm
(define (fill0 lst len)
  (append lst (make-list (- len (length lst)) 0)))

(define (add lst1 lst2)
  (let ((maxlen (max (length lst1) (length lst2))))
    (map + (fill0 lst1 maxlen) (fill0 lst2 maxlen))))
```

or, for fun, the other way round:

```scm
(define (add lst1 lst2)
  (let ((minlen (min (length lst1) (length lst2))))
    (append 
     (map + (take lst1 minlen) (take lst2 minlen))
     (drop lst1 minlen)
     (drop lst2 minlen))))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to pre-compute the lengths of the lists and add zeroes to the end of one or the other of the lists. Here we solve the problem with a simple recursion:

```
(define (add xs ys)
  (cond ((and (pair? xs) (pair? ys))
          (cons (+ (car xs) (car ys)) (add (cdr xs) (cdr ys))))
        ((pair? xs) (cons (car xs) (add (cdr xs) ys)))
        ((pair? ys) (cons (car ys) (add xs (cdr ys))))
        (else '())))
```

That works for all of Oscar's tests:

```
> (add '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2 3))
(2 4 6 4)
> (add '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3 4))
(2 4 6 4)
> (add '(1 2 3 0) '(1 2 3 4))
(2 4 6 4)
```

If you like, you can write that using a named-let and get the same results:

```
(define (add xs ys)
  (let loop ((xs xs) (ys ys) (zs '()))
    (cond ((and (pair? xs) (pair? ys))
            (loop (cdr xs) (cdr ys) (cons (+ (car xs) (car ys)) zs)))
          ((pair? xs) (loop (cdr xs) ys (cons (car xs) zs)))
          ((pair? ys) (loop xs (cdr ys) (cons (car ys) zs)))
          (else (reverse zs)))))
```

Have fun!

Comment: You don't need to continue to recur if one of the lists is no longer a pair. Just return the pair (in this case what is left of the longer list)

Answer (score 1):

A yet simpler version.

```
(define (add x y)
  (cond ((and (pair? x) (pair? y))
         (cons (+ (car x) (car y))
               (add (cdr x) (cdr y))))
        ((pair? x) x)
        (else y)))
```